# How to Inherit field values of a taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I have quite a large taxonomy term hierarchy with several data fields. Most of time childs and parents have the save values. I'm trying to avoid duplicating the information and thinking about organizing some kind of inheritance. So that value of a field of a term is looked in the term, then if it's empty, in it's parent, and so on.

I'll do some calculations on that values, it's easy using the [taxonomy_get_parents_all](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents_all/7%20taxonomy_get_parents_all) api function. But what puzzles me is how to make Drupal take these inherited values into account when it renders term pages.

It probably has to do with [hook_taxonomy_term_load](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.api.php/function/hook_taxonomy_term_load/7), but how to do it properly, so that user can edit actual term values, but in all other places the inherited values are taken into account?